# Visual studio 2022 Diagnostic tool always shows "No data has been collected yet"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, diagnostic-tools

The diagnostic tools in Visual Studio 2022 Community have stopped working. It shows it's recording the CPU profile but whenever I pause the program to see the results, the tools say "There is no data collected."

It was working at one point, and as far as I'm aware, I didn't change anything and if I go into the filter drop-down menu it shows everything except "Hide native code" is selected.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide  code example and steps to reproduce your problem? Does the latest Visual Studio 2022 still have problem?

Answer (score 7):

In my case it happened due to service 'Visual Studio Collector Service 150" being stopped, or disabled, and therefore, not running. Once you enable the service, and re-run 'debug', diagnostic tools seem to be working, again.

Comment: Work like a charm, thanks

Comment: Worked for me, too, although the service was running. I simply restarted it, and got back my diagnostic tools.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen for a few reasons

- Your code did not execute. The program, if it started properly, didn't get as far as running your code. Put a break-point at the start of your particular code section and see if Visual Studio stops there.
- You didn't include program profile information in the build. Are you building a Debug version, have you turned off debug information or profiling information.
- You are building with options that prevent profiling information from being included.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue today. The Diagnostic Tools have been restored and are now functioning properly after updating Visual Studio 2022 to the latest version. The update process appeared to essentially reinstall VS, which I believe reset the VS from its unexpected state.